# Does LogisticRegression need NxN matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have large dataframe for classification task. I performed simple preprocessing with median input for missing values and here is my model

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'))
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features)
    ]
)

model = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('logisticregressor', LogisticRegression())
])

# some data gaining

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df.iloc[:,df.columns != 'label'], df.iloc[:,df.columns == 'label'], test_size=0.33, random_state=42
)

print(f"X_train.shape is {X_train.shape}")
print(f"y_train.shape is {y_train.values.ravel().shape}")

model.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

But I got

```
X_train.shape is (3359775, 13)
y_train.shape is (3359775,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "projects/1/train.py", line 61, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 335, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py", line 1417, in fit
    for class_, warm_start_coef_ in zip(classes_, warm_start_coef))
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1041, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 859, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 777, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 208, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 572, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 263, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 263, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py", line 688, in _logistic_regression_path
    Y_multi = lbin.fit_transform(y)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py", line 460, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(y).transform(y)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py", line 491, in transform
    sparse_output=self.sparse_output)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py", line 683, in label_binarize
    Y = Y.toarray()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 1025, in toarray
    out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/dsenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 1185, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 82.1 TiB for an array with shape (3359775, 3359775) and data type int64
```

You can see that size of my data is (3359775, 13) where N = 3359775.
Why is NxN matrix constructed inside? Are there ways to avoid it?

Comment: @ChappyHickens while Dask is awesome, I think their question is more "why is the matrix transposed?" than how they can process 82TB on some cluster

Comment: @ti7 Dask would be a way to avoid constructing the NxN matrix. The question is not about a matrix transposition from what I can tell, but about  1) why such a large matrix is constructed and 2) ways to avoid it. My comment (that was deleted?) addressed the second part of the question.

Comment: hmm - someone must have mashed "no longer needed"(?) and then reviewers must have thought my comment totally dismissed yours (when really we need to wait for input from Nourless); by all means return it as it may aid them!